# IRLML9301PBF as high side switching for 5 V, 2 A load from a 3.3 V uC?

Tags: microcontroller, 5v, 3.3v, high-side, p-channel

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyU0w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would like to cut off the power to my APA102-LED-strip during uC sleep -
as the standby current of these strips is relative high.

The strip is directly powered via the 5 V from the USB powerbank.
Theoretically it can draw up to 2.4 A@5 V = 12 W.
In normal usage it will be ~1 A (5 W)
The uC (ESP32-S3) is a 3.3 V type.
I think I need a high-side switch for the LED-power path.

So I need a P-channel MOSFET with 3.3 V logic level and ~3 A or similar.
For this I found at my available/favorite reseller (reichelt.de)

- IRLML6402PBF [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A100/IRLML6402PBF-IR.pdf)
- IRLML9301TRPBF [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/IRLML9301PBF.pdf)
- AO3413 [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A100/AO3413_SPEC.pdf)

First two labeled as logic level - third just found by price sorting.

Am I correct with my assumptions that all of these would work?
Am I missing something?
Every time I have to select MOSFETs I have to relearn how to read these datasheets properly and find the correct VDSon information.
So I am looking forward to some educational answers ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I think I need a high-side switch for the LED-power path.*

I agree with that. A low-side switch won't work because the clock and data lines would also need to be switched.

> *Am I correct with my assumptions that all of these would work? Am I
> missing something?*

The design you have proposed is flawed. The flaw lies in how you hope to drive the p-channel MOSFET. The problem I see is that the p-channel MOSFET's source is connected to 5 volts but, the gate can be driven **no higher** than 3.3 volts hence, the MOSFET will not deactivate fully.

There are ways around this by using an extra transistor of course.

> *So I need a P-channel MOSFET with 3.3 V logic level and ~3 A or
> similar.*

Not really; the source is tied to +5 volts and you can easily pull the gate down to 0 volts so, a 5 volt logic level would work. The problem you have is that your proposed design cannot properly deactivate the MOSFET.

Comment: thanks for your explanation - really clear now what i missed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in another answer, the issue is about your OUT1 line that can't go high enough to interdict conduction in the MOSFET.

You can employ many solutions, like

- adding an NMOS as inverter at OUT1, with a pull-up at 5V (this will revert your signal polarity)
- adding a 5V powered buffer, like a 74LVC1G17, better if with pull-up to 5V (let's call it R2) and still a series resistor to OUT1 (say R1); keeping the ratio of R2/R1 around 8...10, just to promote the higher level
- using a high-side switch, which is designed right for that, and will have additional protection features; I just pick one randomly, [BTS5090](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-power-switches/high-side-switches/profet-plus-12v-automotive-smart-high-side-switch/bts5090-1eja)

Note that the second solution (the pull-up addition) could *nearly* work even with your PMOS alone, but it's... meh...

Comment: thanks for point out other solutions!  i like the *ready made* high-side switches! so will have a look at what distributor has some.. and with a short look at mouser - they are not so more pricey i first thought.. definitely worth the easiness ;-)!

Comment: @StefanKrügers-light Searching for a more targeted device you can find other ones, like this one then: https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/AP22615AWU-7

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjp4u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Perhaps there might be a glitch during startup depending on how fast the MCU will output high compared to the R2 pull-up. Test and see.

Comment: thanks for your diagram. that makes it clearer - also i had to read the *why* in Andy aka answer ;-)

Comment: @StefanKrügers-light Yes, I saw no point in explaining it again as a copy-paste. It was the schematic which was missing for any beginners finding themselves here with the same issue.